# Available edits to Work Order Overview FSL mobile

Tags: field-service-lightning, service, work-order

I am attempting to make edits to what Salesforce refers to as the "work order carousel" on FSL mobile. Particularly the Work Order Overview layout. I would like to edit the Service Appointment card and remove the Contact information found in this layout. 
The related knowledge article is here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mfs_work_order_overview.htm&type=5
This defines the WO Overview but not how to make edits.

Comment: You can check WorkOrder --> Compact Layout to update FSL Mobile Screen.

Comment: did you find anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove contact information on Overview Layout you need to set field level security(Unchecked for that particular Profile ) for contact field on Work Order Object
The Reason why it shows all the cards in overview is because contact is the child object to the WorkOrder.
Now on FSL App You wont see the contact information on Overview.